# Can't log in to chat.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, chat

I was unable to connect to Chat, but finally it worked. Then I got disconnected/logged out of chat, and now I am unable to log in to chat. I closed the browser and re-opened after clearing out all cookies and cache. I logged into Stack Exchange first. I logged into Stack Overflow first. It is still not allowing me to log in to chat.stackoverflow.com. What is wrong?

I have also disabled all browser addons and plugins. The same thing happens on any browser.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to log in though Stack Overflow, click the chat link, and create a new chat room.

See if you can use the chat room I created by [clicking the direct link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60263/quick-test-room-delete-tomorrow-if-you-want). Usually, the site is pretty good about logging you in automatically.

If you still can't, there might be a issue with the browser not wanting to log you in when coming from Stack Overflow. Did you try the log in link on [the chat page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) at the top? Did you try another browser? Reboot? Another Computer?

Comment: Thanks, I tried all the things you mentioned, but it's still not working.

Comment: @TechDude Even on a new computer? You have met the rep requirement of only 20 rep. I'm not sure what to tell you. It seems specific to your account, as I was able to log in.

Comment: Yes, even on a new computer. I don't know what it is. I had been having trouble logging in to begin with, but then I logged in to chat for about 15 minutes only for it to stop working again. Strange.